# Indexing nested lists in R

Tags: r

I have a nested list:

```
>str(myNestedList)
List of 9
$ : num [1:33, 1:4] 42.84 36.49 12.17 27.64 4.33 ...
$ : num [1, 1:4] 61 NA NA NA
$ : num [1:27, 1:4] 6.63 NA NA NA 1.75 ...
$ : num [1:17, 1:4] 63.6 135.2 NA 31.9 NA ...
$ : num [1:5, 1:4] NA 19.6 42.4 22.3 41.7 ...
$ : num [1:45, 1:4] NA 20.3 12.1 78.4 343.9 ...
$ : num [1:13, 1:4] 47.1 14.3 130.6 12.2 28.2 ...
$ : num [1, 1:4] 315 NA NA NA
$ : num [1:65, 1:4] 21.16 5.31 13.1 3.23 25.77 ...
```

I want to index the nested list using the last dimension like so:

```
myOuputList <- list()
for(i in 1:4) {
  myOutputList[[i]] <- myFunction(myNestedList[[,]][,i])
}
```

Would a kind soul please explain why this does not work and how to fix it?

Cheers,

Comment: That's not a nested list. It's a list of matrices.

Comment: How about `as.list(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, ll)))` where `ll` is your list of matrices?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lists would be extracted with `[[` and the matrices (not lists) with [,] indexing, but you need to give the functions something to work with. (At the moment you are not.) So if you wantend the 4h matrix and the i,j values were 10 and 3 this would deliver that value:

```
 myNestedList[[4]][10,3]
```

The evaluation proceeds left to right. Wrapped in a function and assuming from context that you only wanted the i-th column (which is a bit confusing since `i` usually refers to rows):

```
 pull.ith.col.from.nth.mat <- function(lis, n, i) lis[[n]][ , i]
```

Comment: thanks! Not exactly what I was after but you led me to realize a flaw in my thinking. I was misinterpreting the output of str(). I thought I had a list of lists vs a list of matrices.

Answer (score 3):

There is some goofy syntax in R for sure, to reiterate what others have said:

```
 a<-list()        #instantiates a 
 a[[1]]<-list()   #instantiates the first row of a 
 a[[1]][1]<-'col1'#puts values in the first row 
 a[[1]][2]<-'col2'
 a[[1]][3]<-'col3'
 a[[2]]<-list()   #Each row requires independent instantiation (if that's a word)
 a[[2]][1]<-'val1'
 a[[2]][2]<-'val2'
 a[[2]][3]<-'val3'
 print(a)
```

This pattern extends into higher dimensional lists,

```
a <- list()
a[[1]]<-list()
a[[1]][[1]]<-list()          # When Assigning lists() to a location use [[]]
a[[1]][[1]][[1]]<-c(1,2,3)   # When Assigning vectors to a location use [[]]
a[[1]][[1]][2]<-7.2# some times you can get away with [] but sticking with [[]]
a[[1]][[1]]['key']<-'value'                         # seems to be the safe bet.
print(a)
```

The '$' as well as [] can be used to access lists at particular indices but integer indices must be designated with [] is probably the safe bet.

```
a <- list()
a[[1]] <- 'one'
a[['key']] <- 'value'
print (paste('a[1]  ::',a[1]))
print (paste('a[[1]]::',a[[1]]))
print (paste('a["key"]  ::',a["key"]))
print (paste('a$key::',a$key))# a$1 would cause an error with int indices
print (paste('a[["key"]]::',a[["key"]]))
```

The double brackets feel unnecessary and it would be nice if list() behaved more like python {}dictionaries but once you get used to the [[]] it is very much similar.()
You can chose your own stance on the variety of ways to do the same thing in R, as someone who has only come to it recently I find it often difficult to read but it is quite the language and the hassle might just be worth it.
enjoy,
~

Comment: I'm only looking at this because I got a system notice about my answer, but I think you are perhaps misleading people when you say that `a[[1]]<-list()` "instantiates a row". In R lists are not really rows or columns but in the special case of data.frames, this would be instantiating a column rather than a row. Perhaps with an additional 4 years of experience, you might want to revise your answer?