# Indexing nested list structure in R

Tags: r, list, reference

I have transitioned from STATA to R, and I was experimenting with different data types so that R's data structures are clear in my mind.

Here's how I set up my data structure:

```
b<-list(u=5,v=12)
c<-list(u=7)
j<-list(name="Joe",salary=55000,union=T)
bcj<-list(b,c,j)
```

Now, I was trying to figure out different ways to access u=5. I believe there are three ways:

**Try1:**

```
bcj[[1]][[1]]
```

I got 5. Correct!

**Try2:**

```
bcj[[1]][["u"]]
```

I got 5. Correct!

**Try3:**

```
bcj[[1]]$u
```

I got 5. Correct!

**Try4**

```
bcj[[1]][1][1]
```

Here's what I got:

```
bcj[[1]][1][1]
$u
[1] 5

class(bcj[[1]][1][1])
[1] "list"
```

**Question 1: Why did this happen?**

Also, I experimented with the following:

```
bcj[[1]][1][1][1][1][1]
$u
[1] 5

class(bcj[[1]][1][1][1][1][1])
[1] "list"
```

**Question 2: I would have expected an error because I don't think so many lists exist in bcj, but R gave me a list. Why did this happen?**

PS: I did look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634810/indexing-nested-lists-in-r) on SO, but it's talking about a different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is sufficient to answer your question. Consider a **length-1 list**:

```
x <- list(u = 5)
#$u
#[1] 5
length(x)
#[1] 1

x[1]
x[1][1]
x[1][1][1]
...
```

always gives you the same:

```
#$u
#[1] 5
```

In other words, `x[1]` will be identical to `x`, and you fall into infinite recursion. No matter how many `[1]` you write, you just get `x` itself.

> If I create `t1<-list(u=5,v=7)`, and then do `t1[2][1][1][1]`...this works as well. However, `t1[[2]][2]` gives `NA`

---

That is the difference between `[[` and `[` when indexing a list. Using `[` will always end up with a list, while `[[` will take out the content. Compare:

```
z1 <- t1[2]
## this is a length-1 list
#$v
#[1] 7
class(z1)
# "list"

z2 <- t1[[2]]
## this takes out the content; in this case, a vector
#[1] 7
class(z2)
#[1] "numeric"
```

When you do `z1[1][1]...`, as discussed above, you always end up with `z1` itself. While if you do `z2[2]`, you surely get an `NA`, because `z2` has only one element, and you are asking for the 2nd element.

---

Perhaps this post and my answer there is useful for you: [Extract nested list elements using bracketed numbers and names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37958879/4891738)?

Comment: Thanks Zheyuan. This helps. Interestingly, if I create t1<-list(u=5,v=7), and then do t1[2][1][1][1]...this works as well. However, t1[[2]][2] gives NA..

Comment: This is a normal behavior. The fundamental unit in R is a vector. `t1[2]` returns a vector (of length one). `t1[2][1]` returns the first entry in that vector, which is a number, but in a sense it is also a vector of length one, and this can keep going on. As for `t1[[2]][2]`, you are asking for an element that does not exist, so NA instead of an error message.

Comment: Zheyuan and p_barill, Thanks for wonderful comments. I know you have already answered my question, but I as I think about this, I have a quick question. In the t1 example (i.e. t1<-list(u=5,v=7)), length (t1) is 2, which makes sense. Also, length (t1[1]) is 1, which also makes sense, because there is only one list. However, is there any way that length (t1[1]) could be greater than 1? I am not quite sure, so I thought of asking you guys. I'd appreciate your thoughts. Sorry for the back-and-forth.

Comment: Thanks Zheyuan. I think I was curious to know whether we can construct a list (or data frame) such that the length of the "first" list in a nested list would be >1. I apologize for being unclear in my question. In all the examples I have gone through Norman Matloff's book, the length appears to be 1. Even in my bcj example above, the length of bcj[1], bcj[2] and bcj[3] is 1.

Comment: Yes, Zheyuan. I think I agree with your comment about [[]]. The reason I was thinking about length > 1 for [] is that if the length of [] will "always" be equal to 1, then it would be redundant to call such a function (or even provide such a functionality). Again, I think our discussion is now of out--of-scope of the original question posted by me. I sincerely appreciate your efforts in answering my question.

Comment: Fantabulous! Perfect! You are awesome. I wish I could give you 5000 points!